# using Case statement in @Filter annotation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, filter

i am having a table in hibernate which looks like below

Price
with below fields and values

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| price_id  |  price | effective_date (mm/dd/yyyy)  |inactive | product_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         |  10    |  01/01/2015                  | N      |   4
| 2         |  11    |  02/01/2015                  | N      |   4
| 3         |  12    |  08/29/2015                  | N      |   4
| 6         |  10    |  09/02/2015                  | Y      |   4
| 7         |  9     |  09/05/2015                  | N      |   4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

price_id is some unique id.
price is the cost of the product
effective_date - price applied to the product when the system date is reached that date.
active - determines whether the price is active or not applicable to the product.
product_id - is the product whose price are applicable

i have a entity in hibernate for the above table. with the hibenate @filter annotation as below

```
    @FilterDef(name = "currentPrice")

    @Filter(name = "currentPrice", condition = "price_id  =(SELECT DISTINCT (CASE  
            WHEN (SELECT MAX (pp.price_id) 
                  FROM price pp 
                 WHERE pp.product_id = product_id 
                   AND pp.effective_date <= SYSDATE 
                   AND (pp.inactive != 'Y' OR pp.inactive IS NULL)) IS NULL 
             THEN (SELECT MAX (pp.price_id) 
                     FROM price pp 
                    WHERE pp.product_id = product_id 
                      AND pp.effective_date IN ( 
                             SELECT MIN (pp.effective_date) 
                               FROM price pp 
                              WHERE pp.product_id = product_id 
                                AND (pp.inactive != 'Y' OR pp.inactive IS NULL ))) 
          ELSE (SELECT MAX (pp.price_id) 
                  FROM price pp 
                 WHERE pp.product_id = product_id 
                   AND pp.effective_date <= SYSDATE 
                   AND (pp.inactive != 'Y' OR pp.inactive IS NULL)) 
       END) 
  FROM price prodPrice where prodPrice.product_id = product_id)"
   public List<PriceData> getPrices() {
        return this.prices;
    }
i am trying to fetch the active price for the that is matching the system date in the filter.
```

Question: when  i was using hibernate 3.2.6.ga version.

Now when i upgrade to hibernate 3.6.10 or 4.2.20, i am getting issues.
the query formed by hibernate is appending the alias name to the MAX aggregate function.
due to which the SQLGrammer exception is logged.

2015-08-29 17:52:15,092 WARN  (http-8082-1) [SqlExceptionHelper(logExceptions:144)] SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
2015-08-29 17:52:15,093 ERROR (http-8082-1) [SqlExceptionHelper(logExceptions:146)] ORA-00904: "PRODUCTPRI0_"."MAX": invalid identifier

is there any solution to fix this. why the higher version of hibernate causing issue with case when statement in @Filter

Comment: I was able make the above work using the deduceAliasInjectionPoints = false. which suppress the alias injector usage. refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html  link search for deduceAliasInjectionPoints

Comment: We can also use alias injector, using @SqlFrangmentAlias annotation in the filter to achieve the addition of entity alias to the filter query. 

@Filter( name="name", condition=" field1 = {aliasName}.field1", deduceAliasInjectionPoints=false, aliases = {@SqlFragmentAlias(alias="aliasName", entity=Entity.class)})